# In operator without () in query expression

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

error:

> In operator without () in query expression '(EnrollmentsTbl.UserName LIKE ? IN ''      [;DATABASE=e:\web\mcfrsitcom0\htdocs\trackingHIPAA\App_Data\subsite.mdb])'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: In operator without () in query expression '(EnrollmentsTbl.UserName LIKE ? IN '' [;DATABASE=e:\web\mcfrsitcom0\htdocs\trackingHIPAA\App_Data\subsite.mdb])'.

not sure why is asking for () in different place?

here is SELECT in ASPX vb.net

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum, EnrollmentsTbl.UserName, EnrollmentsTbl.SubmitTime, EnrollmentsTbl.ClassName, EnrollmentsTbl.ClassDate, EnrollmentsTbl.ClassTime, EnrollmentsTbl.Enrolled, EnrollmentsTbl.WaitListed, EnrollmentsTbl.Instructor, EnrollmentsTbl.DateCompleted, EnrollmentsTbl.Completed, EnrollmentsTbl.Walkin FROM EnrollmentsTbl WHERE (EnrollmentsTbl.UserName LIKE ? IN '' [;DATABASE=e:\web\mcfrsitcom0\htdocs\trackingHIPAA\App_Data\subsite.mdb])"
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? You can either use `LIKE` or `IN` but you can't use both at once and if you do you IS it needs to be in the format `Where UserName IN ('username 1', username 2',...)`. Alternatively you can next a select statement in the `IN`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example, I'm SELECTing from both DB's

Comment: I'm selecting username that already exist in "IN" DB to find it in main DB, if it doesn't exist in "IN" DB then no records are returned.

Comment: if you want to join two tables together from two databases you are better off setting it up as a linked table. It looks like you are putting part of your connection string in your select statement though. that's not going to work.

Comment: I'm currently using this IN statement in an UPDATE and it works fine . I'm not able to link tables so this was my next solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your other comments it sounds like you want to do something more like this:

```vb
SelectCommand = _
        "SELECT EnrollmentsTbl.AutoNum, EnrollmentsTbl.UserName, EnrollmentsTbl.SubmitTime, " & _
            "EnrollmentsTbl.ClassName, EnrollmentsTbl.ClassDate, EnrollmentsTbl.ClassTime, " & _
            "EnrollmentsTbl.Enrolled, EnrollmentsTbl.WaitListed, EnrollmentsTbl.Instructor, " & _
            "EnrollmentsTbl.DateCompleted, EnrollmentsTbl.Completed, EnrollmentsTbl.Walkin " & _
        "FROM EnrollmentsTbl " & _
        "WHERE EnrollmentsTbl.UserName IN " & _
            "(" & _
                "SELECT OtherColumnName " & _
                "FROM [;DATABASE=e:\web\mcfrsitcom0\htdocs\trackingHIPAA\App_Data\subsite.mdb].OtherTableName" & _
            ")"
```

I just tried a similar query in C# using OleDb and it worked fine.

Comment: thanks, I left off the select part in the remote DB - thanks for the  fix - thats what I get for moving the SQL from UPDATE.

Answer (score 2):

The `IN` operator looks for values that exist in a static list of values or the results of a subquery.  You seem to be using it to find values in a *database file*.

You also combine it with the `LIKE` operator which doesn't make sense.

Perhaps if you explained better what you're *trying* to do an alternative could be found.

Comment: in the end i'm trying to find records in one DB that are NOT IN the other, but for my initial run I want to find records I know are there to make sure my syntax is correct. - In other words, looking for username to make sure its in both enrollments table in two different DB in different locations