# Get records NOT IN local DB but in remote DB

Tags: sql, ms-access

looking for correct syntax for how to get all records that do "NOT EXISTS" in the main DB but do in the Remote DB

The following code gets all blank records from remote DB not sure if it relates to local DB.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="<%$ ConnectionStrings:accessConnectionString %>"      
    SelectCommand="SELECT EnrollmentsTbl.UserName, EnrollmentsTbl.SubmitTime, EnrollmentsTbl.ClassName, 
    EnrollmentsTbl.ClassDate, EnrollmentsTbl.ClassTime, EnrollmentsTbl.Enrolled, EnrollmentsTbl.WaitListed, EnrollmentsTbl.Instructor, 
    EnrollmentsTbl.DateCompleted, EnrollmentsTbl.Completed, EnrollmentsTbl.Walkin 
    FROM [;DATABASE=e:\subsite.mdb].EnrollmentsTbl AS XXX 
    LEFT JOIN EnrollmentsTbl ON XXX.UserName = EnrollmentsTbl.UserName WHERE (EnrollmentsTbl.UserName Is Null)">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [In operator without () in query expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698305/in-operator-without-in-query-expression)

Comment: The sample code doesn't fail? It just returns incorrect records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard" approach is to use an outer join and filter on nulls, paraphrased as:

```
select r.*
from remote_table r
left join local_table l
  on l.id = r.id
where l.id is null
```

Comment: Would I still need the WHERE clause since it's a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: The where clause is essential to this working. When the join misses (meaning there's no local row), all columns of the left-joined row will be null, and you use that fact to filter out the hits to leave only the misses, which is what you want.

Comment: only get error: "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: That probably means you have a placeholder (usually a "?") in your query and have created a prepared statement and are not assigning a value to the parameter that's generated for the placeholder.

Comment: changed code in original question - I did @bohemiam suggestion and produced a table of all blank rows... seems to be remote DB number of records but all blank in GRIDVIEW

Answer (score 0):

Here was final solution that worked:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="<%$ ConnectionStrings:accessConnectionString %>"      
    SelectCommand="SELECT XXX.UserName, XXX.SubmitTime, XXX.ClassName, 
    XXX.ClassDate, XXX.ClassTime, XXX.Enrolled, XXX.WaitListed, XXX.Instructor, 
    XXX.DateCompleted, XXX.Completed, XXX.Walkin 
    FROM [;DATABASE=e:\subsite.mdb].EnrollmentsTbl AS XXX 
    LEFT JOIN Users ON XXX.UserName = Users.UserName WHERE (Users.UserName Is Null)">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```